# Downdated TeX-Files?

Tags: errors

Question:

Hey everyone. I tried to install some packages (subfigure/subfig and mcode), but destroyed my whole TeX. I am running Kubuntu 12.04, downloaded the files, created the .sty-Files and put them into the associated folder. 
Then I ran

```
sudo texhash
```

and to be sure

```
 sudo latex /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/*
```

which is the folder, my .sty-files are in. Now, whenever I want to produce a .pdf File, Kile shows the following error (for error-code scroll further down):

[image: Screenshot]

I guess, I did not up- but downdated TeX
Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{geometry}                
\geometry{a4paper}                   
\usepackage{graphicx,subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=Blue, citecolor=Blue, urlcolor=Blue, backref=page]{hyperref}
% Sprachpaket
\usepackage[english]{babel} 
% Umlaute
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

% Zur Darstellung von URLs im Literaturverzeichnis
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

Error Code:

---

```
*****     PDFLaTeX output: 
*****     cd "/home/david/Projekte/TWIN-SEA/TeX"
*****     pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode Matrix.tex
*****
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)
entering extended mode
(./Matrix.tex
LaTeX2e <2009/09/24>
Babel <v3.8l> and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, loaded.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/report.cls
Document Class: report 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/base/size11.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/etc/texmf/tex/latex/config/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)

LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 406, version
`2010/12/07' of package ltxcmds,
but only version
`2009/08/05 v1.0 Some LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
'
is available.

! Undefined control sequence.
l.417 \ltx@IfUndefined
{pdftexversion}{%

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.417 \ltx@IfUndefined{p
dftexversion}{%

! Package pdftex.def Error: Option `pdftex' requires pdfTeX,
(pdftex.def)                but pdfTeX features are missing.
(pdftex.def)                Loading of this driver file is aborted.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                              

l.422   }\@ehc

))) (/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/subfig/subfig.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/caption/caption.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/caption/caption3.sty)))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/amssymb.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/amsfonts/amsfonts.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/wasysym/wasysym.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/booktabs/booktabs.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-texlive/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty

! LaTeX Error: File `kvdefinekeys.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.252 \RequirePackage{kvdefinekeys}[2010/03/01]
^^M
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on Matrix.log.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! By the way, that screenshot is really small ;-)

Comment: i can't understand why you chose to do `sudo latex /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/*` -- i'm not surprised that it didn't help much, but that it found and tried to process any files (there's only directories in my directory at that address).  did you copy your downloaded stuff into that directory?  if so, it is not surprising it doesn't work.

Comment: I think, it is better to move the current (faulty) installation to another place and reinstall again, and then place the packages at the right position `texmf-dist/tex/latex/package_name' and afterwards do a `texhash` (as root or via sudo)

Comment: from the path to your latex installation, it seems like you didn't use the package manager provided by ubuntu to install tex. Was it on purpose ? Otherwise you could try to get rid of the faulty installation and use the package manager to reinstall tex. It seems however like mcode.sty is not available from a package, and you might still have to install it by hand.

Comment: Nah, there was not anything on purpose. I am a total Novice on Linux. I guess my installation was just faulty. Linux doesn't know tlmgr either, so I probably just messed up. However, I thought since LaTeX ran, everything is alright. Seems it doesn't and I have to reinstall it. 
Thanks for helping anyhow!

Comment: Well, it's me again. I tried to deinstall tex-live and everything according with the following commands:  
  
    - sudo apt-get purge texlive-latex-recommended  
    - sudo apt-get purge texlive  
    - sudo apt-get autoremove  
    - sudo apt get autoclean  

Every command will end up with:  
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's about an installation problem that cannot be reproduced.